# Split numpy array by unique values in column

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, split

I have a large array that I imported from a csv (`np.recfromcsv`) that I want to divide into smaller arrays by an ID column in said array.
For example my array(a) looks like:

```
[(842, 129826, 2018, 7246, '1/4/2009', 452, '1/4/2009', 452, '1/4/2009')
 (863, 129827, 2018, 7246, '1/7/2009', 452, '1/7/2009', 452, '1/7/2009')
 (890, 129828, 2019, 7246, '1/11/2009', 452, '1/11/2009', 452, '1/11/2009')
 ...,
 (339, 131268, 1085, 4211, '12/1/2009', 220, '12/2/2009', 220, '12/1/2009')
 (376, 131535, 1085, 4211, '12/8/2009', 220, '12/9/2009', 220, '12/8/2009')
 (470, 131536, 1087, 4211, '12/28/2009', 220, '12/29/2009', 220, '12/28/2009')]
```

And I would like to split this into arrays based on the third column (2018, 2019, 1085, etc). I've been trying to find a way to use numpy's vsplit method using a list I generated of unique ID values (`id_list = list(set(a['id']))`), however I get the erorr: **ValueError: vsplit only works on arrays of 2 or more dimensions**. Which makes me think the `np.recfromcsv` tool doesn't generate dimensions properly. Should I be using a different import tool?
I have also tried doing this in a simple loop:

```
for e in id_list:
    name = "id" + str(e)
    name = a[a['id']==e]
```

But this generates an error: **SyntaxError: can't assign to operator**. I know the problem is the dynamic variable, but I see no other way to achieve this without overwriting the array for each ID.

I'd really appreciate advice on how to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

To read a column from a recarray you do not pass the index, but the name, for example:

```
my_col = a['id']
```

So that your command will be:

```
id_list = list(set(a['id'])))
```

<sub>Just as an observation.
The `recfromcsv()` works properly. Each field in the structured array (or record array) works like a `1D-array`. Maybe you could try using `np.loadtxt()` passing `delimiter=','`, which will return a `2D-array`.</sub>

Comment: I got the same ValueError using np.loadtxt(), and test.shape reveals it is still a 1D-array: (1890,)

Comment: could you make it available somewhere in the web the a sample of your input file... it seems that something is wrong...

Comment: I've removed some of the superfluous columns for this task and put it here: http://www.filedropper.com/samplea

Comment: your file is fine... I've updated the answer adding how to access a column from a recarray...

Comment: That is my fault, I attempted to simplify my code for the question and replaced the column name with a number without thinking. The ID list is generating correctly, but I still can't split the array.